# How many indexes will actually get used?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm writing a page that does very simple search queries, resulting in something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE A in (a1, a2, a3) AND B in (b1, b2) AND C in (c1, c2, c3, c4) AND
```

And so on for a variable number of columns, usually ~5. If I create a separate index for each column (one for A, one for B, one for C, not (A,B,C)), will all of them be used in the above query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimizer will try to use an [Index Merge](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html) operation and use the three indices.

Execute the statement with `EXPLAIN` before it to see the indices it can use, and will use. Consider `FORCE INDEX` and see if it makes a difference.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE A in (a1, a2, a3) AND B in (b1, b2) AND C in (c1, c2, c3, c4) AND
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check it:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ...;
```

You'll get a list of executed queries, their types, **used indexes**, and so on...